# How to capture contents of a CALayer that has a CAAnimation applied to it?

Tags: ios, core-animation

I'm interested in recording a sequence of `CoreAnimations` into a video file.  For this I've built a system that renders out the current state of the `CALayer` 30 times a second and composites this into a video.  However, these individual frame renders do not include the `CoreAnimation` changes.

Current method of capturing a frame:

```
[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

In the Core Animation docs it reads:

> Animatable properties can also be explicitly animated. To explicitly
>   animate a property you create an instance of one of Core Animation’s
>   animation classes and specify the required visual effects. An explicit
>   animation doesn’t change the value of the property in the layer, it
>   simply animates it in the display.

Do you know where/how to intercept the actual appearance of the layer, after the `CoreAnimation` has been applied ?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you can call `-presentationLayer` to get a layer that roughly corresponds to the currently displayed version of your layer... There are restrictions, check in `CALayer.h`.

If you aren't able to capture the output at the full 30 frames, you may be able to pause your presentations during capture and then "single step" them, by manipulating the `speed` and `timeOffset` properties of your root layer.

Comment: Tested -presentationLayer, unfortunately although the docs say it should factor in the animation (and the animation of sublayers) it doesn't work in practice.